# Word for Revival? Renewal, Rebirth

Tags: single-word-requests

Hey guys I'm looking for a nice-sounding, obscure word to synonymize the words: revival, rebirth, re-surgence.

Thanks

Comment: What did you find when you looked in a thesaurus? To whom should the word be "unheard-of"?

Comment: If a word is 'unheard of' it isn't a word - it's gibberish. If you mean obscure, then using that word would be a bad idea anyway.

Comment: @superato Yes you are correct. Let's make it obscure. And don't worry about the uses.

Comment: The word is: regurgitate. All jokes aside, what's wrong with a [thesaurus](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/resurrection) look-up? (HINT: as all the words you came up with are actually on that page, the word you're looking for may be **resurrection**.)

Comment: An obscure word is unlikely to be served by a thesaurus lookup, so your question shouldn't be closed as standard reference. Requirements for single-word-requests also include supplying an example sentence or details on how the word will be used, though, and it wouldn't hurt to mention synonyms you've considered and why they're not suitable (e.g., not obscure enough, etc.). Your failure to satisfy the latter two will probably give the close-happy enough reason to close your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wonderful options exist for your obscure synonymy. They include 'neomorphosis', 'neogenesis', 'palingenesis' ('palingenesia', 'palingenesy'), and 'renascence' ('renascency'). Of those, 'renascence' is probably least obscure, and additionally risks confusion with the very similar 'renaissance', so I won't detail that option.

Of the lot, my favorite is 'palingenesis' (along with the variants 'palingenesia' and 'palingenesy').

> **palingenesis**, *n.*
>   1. Regeneration, rebirth; revival, resuscitation; an instance of this. Also *fig.* Cf. **palingenesia** *n.*
>   <sub>In philosophy and natural science, formerly applied *spec.* to the (supposed) regeneration of living organisms from ashes or putrefying matter, to the preformation theory of Charles Bonnet (1720–93), and to the persistence of the soul (metempsychosis) or (in Schopenhauer) of the will from one generation to another (now *hist.*). ....</sub>

["palingenesis, n.". OED Online. March 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/136328 (accessed April 10, 2016).]

Of the variants 'palingenesia' and 'palingenesy', 'palingenesia' is defined as equivalent to 'palingenesis'. 'Palingenesy' is defined likewise, but is specifically noted to now be "*arch.* and *rare*" (op. cit.).

'Neomorphosis' or 'neogenesis' might work for you. They are, however, primarily used (when used at all) with reference to biology, and are thus less likely to be apt. Of the two, 'neogenesis' is more likely; note especially sense *(b)*:

> **neogenesis**  *n.*  [after German *Neogenese* (1879 or earlier)] chiefly *Biol.*  *(a)* regeneration or renewed formation of a previously formed substance, tissue, cell type, structure, etc.;  *(b)* the formation of a new type, form, etc.; an instance of this.

["neo-, comb. form". OED Online. March 2016. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/126016 (accessed April 10, 2016).]

> **neomorphosis**  *n. Biol. rare  (a)* regeneration, *spec.* of an organ or structure that is different from any pre-existing organ or structure (*disused*);  *(b)* the formation of a new type or form, esp. by neoteny.

(op. cit.)

Comment: @Asker123  Well? Don't keep us in suspense!

Answer (score 0):

An obscure word, yet less of a direct synonym, would be [metempsychosis](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/metempsychosis). But obscure words should only be used within a specific, appropriate context - obscurity for obscurity's sake is at best pretentious and at worst ridiculous.

More appropriate is the word [renaissance](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/renaissance), which literarily means 'rebirth' and is associated with a revival of art and culture, hence the Renaissance.

Answer (score 0):

[***renascence***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=renascence&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Crenascence%3B%2Cc0)

> *formal* The revival of something that has been dormant:
>   *the renascence of poetry as an oral art*
>
> [Oxford Dictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/fr/definition/anglais_americain/renascence)
>
> *Erwin Panovsky and the [Renascence](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2862914?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents) of the Renaissance*